# Table not updating in joined table and I can't figure out why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am having troubles saving data that is related to a joined table. I am using Rails 4.01 with Devise 3.23 and rolify. I'm fairly new to Rails so this may be a noob question although I've searched everything on SO I can.

Basically when I try to change a role, it doesn't save the data in the joined table, but it doesn't seem to be throwing any errors. I can't find anything in the logs either.
I have the exact same issue with a second joined table. The common denominator is they both join to my users table and I'm using the update action on my User Controller.

I've spent the last two hours trying to find a solution. I thought it might be a strong parameters issue but I can't find the problem. I have tried downgrading to Rails 4.0.0 just in case but no good. I have another app with essentially the same code and no problems.

Here's my User Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    authorize! :index, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def update
    authorize! :update, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params[:user])
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize! :destroy, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    unless user == current_user
      user.destroy
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "Can't delete yourself."
    end
  end

  # new function to set the password without knowing the current password used in our confirmation controller. 
  def attempt_set_password(params)
    p = {}
    p[:password] = params[:password]
    p[:password_confirmation] = params[:password_confirmation]
    update_attributes(p)
  end

  # new function to return whether a password has been set
  def has_no_password?
   self.encrypted_password.blank?
 end

 # new function to provide access to protected method unless_confirmed
 def only_if_unconfirmed
   unless_confirmed {yield}
 end

private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit( :name, :role_ids, :qualification_id, :role, :qualification )
    end

end
```

My User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :qualification

  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  validates :phone, presence: true, format: { with: /1.\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4}/, message: "Must be in 1.555.555.5555 format" }
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :acknowledgement, presence: true


# new function to set the password without knowing the current password used in our confirmation controller. 
def attempt_set_password(params)
  p = {}
  p[:password] = params[:password]
  p[:password_confirmation] = params[:password_confirmation]
  update_attributes(p)
end

# new function to return whether a password has been set
def has_no_password?
  self.encrypted_password.blank?
end

# new function to provide access to protected method unless_confirmed
def only_if_unconfirmed
  pending_any_confirmation {yield}
end

def password_required?
  # Password is required if it is being set, but not for new records
  if !persisted? 
    false
  else
    !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
  end
end

end
```

My Qualification Model:

```
class Qualification < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

My Role Model:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true

  scopify
end
```

Here is my index view to change the role:

```
<h2 class='subheader'>People</h2>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <div class='row collapse'>
      <div class='large-2 columns'><%= link_to user.name, user_path(user) %></div>
      <div class='large-2 columns'><%= user.email %></div>
      <div class='large-2 columns'><%= user.phone %></div>
      <div class='large-2 columns'><%=  user.qualification.name unless user.qualification.nil?%></div>
      <div class='large-2 columns'><%= user.roles.first.name.titleize unless user.roles.first.nil? %></div>
      <div class='large-2 columns'>
        <% if user != current_user %> 
        <a data-reveal-id="role-options-<%= user.id %>" href="#" class="button tiny radius" type="button">Change role</a>
      <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class='large-2 columns'>
        <%= link_to("Delete Person", user_path(user), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete, class: 'button radius tiny') unless user == current_user %></div>
        <hr>
    </div>
<div id="role-options-<%= user.id %>" class="reveal-modal tiny" style="display: none;">
  <%= simple_form_for user, url: user_path(user), html: {:method => :put, class: 'custom' } do |f| %>
  <div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>      
    <h3>Change Role</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.input :role_ids, collection: Role.all, as: :radio_buttons, label_method: lambda {|t| t.name.titleize}, label: false, item_wrapper_class: 'inline', checked: user.role_ids.first %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit "Change Role", :class => "button tiny radius" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>  
<% end %>
```

Here's the relevant excerpt from my log:

```
Started PUT "/users/47" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-20 22:27:59 -0700
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"3kfL/K47ynC4LGF9kh/cAfAadGu8OXhH9kXhxeGPsvo=", "user"=> {"role_ids"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Change Role", "id"=>"47"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "47"]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = ? AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users
Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

I'm pulling my hair out on this one so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: I get no error at all. The table simple does not update.

Comment: What do the `params` look like that are being passed to the `update` method?  These would be in the log file at `log/development.log` (assuming development).

Comment: I've added the relevant section from my log.

Comment: So, what's the output of the following SQL query: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL))) ` if you run it manually against the database.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
...ECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles...
...                               ^

Comment: @DaveOlson in that case there must have some validation due to which its perform rollback

Comment: So, do you have "roles" and "users_roles" tables in your DB?

Comment: Yes I do have both of those tables

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with `rolify` but it doesn't look like your `User` model does anything with the `role_ids` attribute in the params...

Assuming it doesn't, you'd want to iterate over each `role_id` (if they exist) within your controller:

```
def update
  authorize! :update, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'

  @user.update_roles(user_params[:role_ids]) if user_params[:role_ids].present?

  if @user.update_attributes(user_params[:user])
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
  else
    redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
  end
end
```

Then on your `User` model, you'd have:

```
def update_roles(role_ids)
  role_names = Role.find_all_by_id(role_ids).map(&:name)

  role_names.each {|role_name| self.add_role role_name.to_sym }
end
```

Again, I haven't tested this and I'm not overly familiar with `rolify` so someone else may have a better suggestion, but this should at least get you closer.

Comment: I gave it a try but I get the same results as before. Rolify must already do this.